# Adding Prefix in XSLT 3

Tags: xslt-3.0

How to add a prefix (7HH) if the value doesn't start with '7HH'?

Source XML

```
<DATA>
   <Name>90078</Name>
</DATA>
```

Expected output

```
<DATA>
   <Name>7HH90078</Name>
</DATA>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well

```
<xsl:template match="DATA/Name[not(starts-with(., '7HH'))]">
  <xsl:copy expand-text="yes">7HH{.}</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

plus `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` to handle the rest should suffice if you really use an XSLT 3 processor.